# What is the standard way to get a Rust thread out of blocking operations?

Tags: multithreading, rust, terminate

Coming from Java, I am used to idioms along the lines of

```java
while (true) {
  try {
    someBlockingOperation();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread.interrupt(); // re-set the interrupted flag
    cleanup(); // whatever is necessary
    break;
  }
}
```

This works, as far as I know, across the whole JDK for anything that might block, like reading from files, from sockets, from a queue and even for `Thread.sleep()`.

Reading on how this is done in Rust, I find lots of seemingly special solutions mentioned like `mio`, `tokio`. I also find `ErrorKind::Interrupted` and tried to get this `ErrorKind` with sending `SIGINT` to the thread, but the thread seems to die immediately without leaving any (back)trace.

Here is the code I used (note: not very well versed in Rust yet, so it might look a bit strange, but it runs):

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;
use std::thread;

pub fn main() {
    let sub_thread = thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut buffer = [0; 10];
        loop {
            let d = io::stdin().read(&mut buffer);
            println!("{:?}", d);
            let n = d.unwrap();
            if n == 0 {
                break;
            }
            println!("-> {:?}", &buffer[0..n]);
        }
    });

    sub_thread.join().unwrap();
}
```

By "blocking operations", I mean:

- sleep
- socket IO
- file IO
- queue IO (not sure yet where the queues are in Rust)

What would be the respective means to signal to a thread, like `Thread.interrupt()` in Java, that its time to pack up and go home?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no such thing. Blocking means blocking.

Instead, you deliberately use tools that are *non-blocking*. That's where libraries like mio, Tokio, or futures come in — they handle the architecture of sticking all of these non-blocking, asynchronous pieces together.

> `catch (InterruptedException e)`

Rust doesn't have exceptions. If you expect to handle a failure case, that's better represented with a `Result`.

> `Thread.interrupt()`

This doesn't actually do anything beyond setting a flag in the thread that some code may check and then throw an exception for. You could build the same structure yourself. One simple implementation:

```
use std::{
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
        Arc,
    },
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

fn main() {
    let please_stop = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));

    let t = thread::spawn({
        let should_i_stop = please_stop.clone();
        move || {
            while !should_i_stop.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
                println!("Sleeping");
            }
        }
    });

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    please_stop.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

#### Sleep

No way of interrupting, as far as I know. The documentation even says:

> On Unix platforms this function will **not return early due to a signal**

#### Socket IO

You put the socket into nonblocking mode using methods like [`set_nonblocking`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.set_nonblocking) and then handle [`ErrorKind::WouldBlock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.WouldBlock).

See also:

- [Tokio](https://tokio.rs/)
- [async-std](https://async.rs/)

#### File IO

There isn't really a good cross-platform way of performing asynchronous file IO. Most implementations spin up a thread pool and perform blocking operations there, sending the data over something that does non-blocking.

See also:

- [Tokio](https://tokio.rs/)
- [async-std](https://async.rs/)

#### Queue IO

Perhaps you mean something like a [MPSC channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/index.html), in which case you'd use tools like [`try_recv`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_recv).

See also:

- [How to terminate or suspend a Rust thread from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26199926/155423)
- [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423)
- [What does java.lang.Thread.interrupt() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3590000/155423)

Comment: With blocking and interruption it's more complicated. But your "Sleep" reaction is confusing. `sleep` is normal cancellation point (POSIX) additionally from `man 3 sleep` "or until a signal arrives which is not ignored."

See my post:
https://www.quora.com/If-C-can-do-everything-C-can-and-even-more-why-is-C-still-in-use

Comment: @JurajMichalak From the std::thread::sleep docs: "On Unix platforms, the underlying syscall may be interrupted by a spurious wakeup or signal handler. To ensure the sleep occurs for at least the specified duration, this function may invoke that system call multiple times."