# Interrupt std::io::read() in Rust

Tags: rust

I have been trying to write an application that invokes a system command in a separate thread.

The key characteristic is that I want to be able to **kill this command and invoke a new one from the main thread upon request**.

My secondary thread looks like so:

```
let (tx, rx): (mpsc::Sender<String>, mpsc::Receiver<String>) = mpsc::channel();

let child_handle = stoppable_thread::spawn(move |stop| {
  let mut child = Command::new("[the program]").arg(format!("-g {}", gain)).stdout(Stdio::piped()).spawn().expect("naw man");
  let mut childout = child.stdout.as_mut().unwrap();
  while !stop.get() {
    let mut buffer = [0; 128];
    childout.try_read(&mut buffer).unwrap(); // This part makes the code wait for the next output
    // Here the buffer is sent via mpsc irrelevant to the issue
}});
```

The problem is when I send a stop signal (or if I used an mpsc channel to notify the thread to stop) **it waits for the command to output something to stdout.** This is unwanted behavior.

How can I remedy this? How can I interrupt the read() function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to terminate or suspend a Rust thread from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199926/how-to-terminate-or-suspend-a-rust-thread-from-another-thread)

Comment: It does not, This is used in the code snippet, my question is about interrupting the read() command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [kill](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.kill) the child process, which will cause it to close its output, at which point `read` will see an EOF and return. However, this requires sending the child to the parent thread. Something like:

```
let (tx, rx): (mpsc::Sender<String>, mpsc::Receiver<String>) = mpsc::channel();
let (ctx, crx) = mpsc::channel();

let child_handle = stoppable_thread::spawn(move |stop| {
  let mut child = Command::new("[the program]").arg(format!("-g {}", gain)).stdout(Stdio::piped()).spawn().expect("naw man");
  let mut childout = child.stdout.take().unwrap();
  ctx.send (child);
  while !stop.get() {
    let mut buffer = [0; 128];
    childout.try_read(&mut buffer).unwrap(); // This part makes the code wait for the next output
    // Here the buffer is sent via mpsc irrelevant to the issue
}});

// When you want to stop:
let child = crx.recv().unwrap();
child.kill().unwrap();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think of that