# How to catch signals in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write some code that will catch a signal like SIGTERM.

I found [this](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~acrichto/doc/std/io/signal/struct.Listener.html) and I also found [How to handle blocking i/o in Rust, or long running external function calls in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818588/how-to-handle-blocking-i-o-in-rust-or-long-running-external-function-calls-in-g).

But in the current Rust version (0.12 nightly) it seems like that `std::io::signal::Listener` was removed. Did it get put somewhere else? If so can someone point me to how to catch a signal?

Comment: This is a good overview about signals in Rust: https://vorner.github.io/2018/06/28/signal-hook.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that `std::io::signal` module was removed in [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/17673) pull request. It is claimed that proper signals handling was never implemented properly for native runtime, so you likely wouldn't be able to use it now anyway. [This](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/11203) seems to be a tracking issue for this problem.

In the meantime, I think, you will have to drop down to the lowest-level unsafe functions from `libc`.

Answer (score 30):

It seems that it's now fairly trivial to implement this. The [Signal handling section](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/cli-wg/in-depth/signals.html) of Command Line Applications in Rust goes over the concept, and mentions the [ctrlc](https://crates.io/crates/ctrlc) crate to handle that specific signal, and the [signal-hook](https://crates.io/crates/signal-hook) crate to handle signals in general.

Via the guide, with signal-hook it should be as simple as:

```
use std::{error::Error, thread};
use signal_hook::{consts::SIGTERM, iterator::Signals};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let mut signals = Signals::new(&[SIGTERM])?;

    thread::spawn(move || {
        for sig in signals.forever() {
            println!("Received signal {:?}", sig);
        }
    });

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 7):

At the time of writing this answer, there is [an RFC for built-in signals](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1368).

I have had some success using [the `chan-signal` crate](https://github.com/BurntSushi/chan-signal):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate chan;
extern crate chan_signal;

use chan_signal::Signal;

fn main() {
    // Signal gets a value when the OS sent a INT or TERM signal.
    let signal = chan_signal::notify(&[Signal::INT, Signal::TERM]);
    // When our work is complete, send a sentinel value on `sdone`.
    let (sdone, rdone) = chan::sync(0);
    // Run work.
    ::std::thread::spawn(move || run(sdone));

    // Wait for a signal or for work to be done.
    chan_select! {
        signal.recv() -> signal => {
            println!("received signal: {:?}", signal)
        },
        rdone.recv() => {
            println!("Program completed normally.");
        }
    }
}

fn run(_sdone: chan::Sender<()>) {
    println!("Running work for 5 seconds.");
    println!("Can you send a signal quickly enough?");
    // Do some work.
    ::std::thread::sleep_ms(5000);

    // _sdone gets dropped which closes the channel and causes `rdone`
    // to unblock.
}
```

Comment: While this answer was valid at the time of posting, the [chan-signal](https://lib.rs/crates/chan-signal) crate did reach its end-of-life a couple of years ago and is considered deprecated by its author(s).

Comment: The core of the answer is still valid, though. 1) unload the work to a 3rd party code, 2) use approach that minimizes work done in the signal handler itself.