# How can I read from a specific raw file descriptor in Rust?

Tags: unix, io, rust, file-descriptor

> Editor's note: This question is for a version of Rust prior to 1.0. Some answers have been updated to cover Rust 1.0 or up, but not all.

I am writing a systemd socket activated service in Rust. My process is being handed an open file descriptor by systemd.

Are there any Rust IO functions that take a raw file descriptor?

I'm using a Rust nightly before Rust 1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think right now your best bet is probably using the [libc crate](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/libc/index.html) for working with raw file descriptors.

The movement of `FileDesc` to private scope was fallout from the runtime removal a few months back. See this [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/230) for some more context. `std::os::unix` currently has the type `Fd`, and I believe the long term idea is to expose more of the platform-specific functionality in that module.

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/18557) has some more context as well.

Comment: It does seem like libc is the way to go until that API is developed further.

Answer (score 7):

As of Rust 1.1, you can use [`FromRawFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html) to create a [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) from a specific file descriptor, but only on UNIX-like operating systems:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{self, Read},
    os::unix::io::FromRawFd,
};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut f = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(3) };
    let mut input = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut input)?;

    println!("I read: {}", input);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
$ cat /tmp/output
Hello, world!
$ target/debug/example 3< /tmp/output
I read: Hello, world!
```

`from_raw_fd` is unsafe:

> This function is also unsafe as the primitives currently returned have the contract that they are the sole owner of the file descriptor they are wrapping. Usage of this function could accidentally allow violating this contract which can cause memory unsafety in code that relies on it being true.

The created `File` will assume ownership of the file descriptor: when the `File` goes out of scope, the file descriptor will be closed. You can avoid this by using either [`IntoRawFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.IntoRawFd.html) or [`mem::forget`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.forget.html).

See also:

- [How do I write to a specific raw file descriptor from Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54858018/155423)

Answer (score 0):

> Editor's note: This answer is for a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and does not compile in Rust 1.0.

I'm just exploring rust myself, but after searching a bit, came up with the following use of the `native` crate: (using file descriptor "1" for the example -- 1 is `stdout`)

```
extern crate native;
use native::io::file::FileDesc as FileDesc;

fn main() 
{
  let mut f = FileDesc::new(1, true);
  let buf = "Hello, world!\n".as_bytes();

  f.inner_write(buf);
}
```

(Tested with `rustc 0.13.0-nightly`. Note that the `inner_write` method may have been renamed to `write` in more recent versions of `libstd`)

### Update

The `native`crate was recently removed from the standard library and `FileDesc`, while still exists as `std::sys::fs::FileDesc` is no longer public...