# How do I write to a specific raw file descriptor from Rust?

Tags: unix, io, rust, file-descriptor

I need to write to file descriptor 3. I have been searching for it but the documentation is quite poor. The only thing that I have found is the use of `libc` library and the `fdopen` method, but I haven't found any example about how to use it or write on it.

Can anyone provide me an example of writing to a file descriptor in Rust?

Comment: There are several crates on [crates.io](https://crates.io/search?q=file%20descriptor). Did you try any of them yet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`FromRawFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html) to create a [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) from a specific file descriptor, but only on UNIX-like operating systems:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{self, Write},
    os::unix::io::FromRawFd,
};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut f = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(3) };
    write!(&mut f, "Hello, world!")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

```
$ target/debug/example 3> /tmp/output
$ cat /tmp/output
Hello, world!
```

`from_raw_fd` is unsafe because there's no guarantee that the file descriptor is valid or who is actually responsible for that file descriptor.

The created `File` will assume ownership of the file descriptor: when the `File` goes out of scope, the file descriptor will be closed. You can avoid this by using either [`IntoRawFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.IntoRawFd.html) or [`mem::forget`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.forget.html).

See also:

- [How can I read from a specific raw file descriptor in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27665396/155423)

Comment: This works like a charm!! really easy and clean solution!

Comment: It is worth adding that if you do not want to close the _fd_ when `f` is dropped, you can just call `f.into_raw_fd()` (from trait `IntoRawFd`) and discard the return value, that will just be `3`.

Comment: @rodrigo yep, or `mem::forget`

Comment: @Shepmaster: `mem::forget` will work, but I think that if you want to keep the _fd_ opened, just because it was opened when you arrived, then `into_raw_fd()` is the proper way: `mem::forget` might have other undesirable effects, such as not freeing internal buffers or who knows what.

Answer (score 3):

The `libc` crate is "just" a wrapping library to interface between C and Rust so to know how to use a function one should read the manual of the C function, there are many source for that, here one for [`fdopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen):

> The `fdopen()` function associates a stream with the existing file descriptor, `fd`. The mode of the stream (one of the values `"r"`, `"r+"`, `"w"`, `"w+"`, `"a"`, `"a+"`) must be compatible with the mode of the file descriptor. The file position indicator of the new stream is set to that belonging to `fd`, and the error and end-of-file indicators are cleared. Modes `"w"` or `"w+"` do not cause truncation of the file. The file descriptor is not dup'ed, and will be closed when the stream created by `fdopen()` is closed. The result of applying `fdopen()` to a shared memory object is undefined.

Basic use is so:

```
use libc::fdopen;
use std::ffi::CString;

fn main() {
    let mode = CString::new("w").unwrap();
    unsafe {
        let _ = fdopen(3, mode.as_ptr());
    }
}
```

To use it, you could use [`fwrite()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite):

> The function `fwrite()` writes `nmemb` elements of data, each size bytes long, to the stream pointed to by stream, obtaining them from the location given by `ptr`.

So, complete example:

```
use libc::{c_void, fdopen, fwrite};
use std::ffi::CString;

fn main() {
    let mode = CString::new("w").unwrap();
    let file = unsafe {
        let file = fdopen(3, mode.as_ptr());
        if file.is_null() {
            panic!("can't open file");
        }
        file
    };

    let welcome = "Hello world!";

    let result = unsafe { fwrite(welcome.as_ptr() as *const c_void, 1, welcome.len(), file) };
    if result != welcome.len() {
        panic!("write not successful");
    }
}
```