# Force non blocking read with TcpStream

Tags: sockets, tcp, rust

I've got a thread, that maintains a list of sockets, and I'd like to traverse the list, see if there is anything to read, if so - act upon it, if not - move onto the next.  The problem is, as soon as I come across the first node, all execution is halted until something comes through on the read.

I'm using `std::io::Read::read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize>`

From the [doc](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read)

> This function does not provide any guarantees about whether it blocks waiting for data, but if an object needs to block for a read but cannot it will typically signal this via an Err return value.

Digging into the source, the TcpStream Read implementation is

```
impl Read for TcpStream {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> { self.0.read(buf) }
}
```

Which invokes

```
pub fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> IoResult<uint> {
    let fd = self.fd();
    let dolock = || self.lock_nonblocking();
    let doread = |nb| unsafe {
        let flags = if nb {c::MSG_DONTWAIT} else {0};
        libc::recv(fd,
                   buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut libc::c_void,
                   buf.len() as wrlen,
                   flags) as libc::c_int
    };
    read(fd, self.read_deadline, dolock, doread)
}
```

And finally, calls [`read<T, L, R>(fd: sock_t, deadline: u64, mut lock: L, mut read: R)`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/sys/common/net.rs#L387)

Where I can see loops over non blocking reads until data has been retrieved or an error has occurred.

Is there a way to force a non-blocking read with `TcpStream`?

Comment: why don't you start a thread per socket?

Comment: @ker This implementation is for an estimated connection time of 5-30min and should be capable of handling around 200k concurrent connections.  I am going under the assumption that amount of threads is a bad thing, but am currently trying to figure out a way to calculate this, as this would be plan B

Comment: You might want to have a look to AsyncIO libraries, such as https://github.com/carllerche/mio

Comment: Looks like a solid library, but I don't need all of the io on the stream to be async.  I think I'll just implement a separate trait for this specific purpose on this project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It should be noted, that as of Rust 1.9.0, `std::net::TcpStream` has added functionality:

[`fn set_nonblocking(&self, nonblocking: bool) -> Result<()>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.set_nonblocking)

**Original Answer**

Couldn't exactly get it with TcpStream, and didn't want to pull in a separate lib for IO operations, so I decided to set the file descriptor as Non-blocking before using it, and executing a system call to read/write.  Definitely not the safest solution, but less work than implementing a new IO lib, even though [MIO](https://github.com/carllerche/mio) looks great.

```
extern "system" {
    fn read(fd: c_int, buffer: *mut c_void, count: size_t) -> ssize_t;
}

pub fn new(user: User, stream: TcpStream) -> Socket {

    // First we need to setup the socket as Non-blocking on POSIX
    let fd = stream.as_raw_fd();
    unsafe {
        let ret_value = libc::fcntl(fd,
            libc::consts::os::posix01::F_SETFL,
            libc::consts::os::extra::O_NONBLOCK);

        // Ensure we didnt get an error code
        if ret_value < 0 {
            panic!("Unable to set fd as non-blocking")
        }
    }

    Socket {
        user: user,
        stream: stream
    }
}

pub fn read(&mut self) {
    let count = 512 as size_t;
    let mut buffer = [0u8; 512];
    let fd = self.stream.as_raw_fd();

    let mut num_read = 0 as ssize_t;
    unsafe {
        let buf_ptr = buffer.as_mut_ptr();
        let void_buf_ptr: *mut c_void = mem::transmute(buf_ptr);
        num_read = read(fd, void_buf_ptr, count);
        if num_read > 0 {
            println!("Read: {}", num_read);
        }

        println!("test");
    }
}
```