# How can I read non-blocking from stdin?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to check whether data is available on `stdin` in Rust, or to do a read that returns immediately with the currently available data?

My goal is to be able to read the input produced for instance by cursor keys in a shell that is setup to return all read data immediately. For instance with an equivalent to: `stty -echo -echok -icanon min 1 time 0`.

I suppose one solution would be to use ncurses or similar libraries, but I would like to avoid any kind of large dependencies.

So far, I got only blocking input, which is not what I want:

```
let mut reader = stdin();
let mut s = String::new();

match reader.read_to_string(&mut s) {...} // this blocks :(
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most operating systems default to work with the standard input and output in a blocking way. No wonder then that the Rust library follows in stead.

To read from a blocking stream in a non-blocking way you might create a separate thread, so that the extra thread blocks instead of the main one. Checking whether a blocking file descriptor produced some input is similar: spawn a thread, make it read the data, check whether it produced any data so far.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/ArtemGr/db40ae04b431a95f2b78) a piece of code that I use with a similar goal of processing a pipe output interactively and that can hopefully serve as an example. It sends the data over a [channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/channels.html), which supports the [try_recv](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_recv) method - allowing you to check whether the data is available or not.

[Someone has told me](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2nka2k/interactive_pipe_reading/cmfbe5w) that [mio](https://github.com/carllerche/mio) might be used to read from a pipe in a non-blocking way, so you might want to check it out too. I suspect that passing the stdin file descriptor (0) to [Receiver::from_raw_fd](https://docs.rs/mio/0.8.5/mio/unix/pipe/struct.Receiver.html) should just work.

Comment: pub fn init() -> Receiver<ControlKeys> {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<ControlKeys>();
    thread::spawn(move|| {
        while true {
            tx.send(read_stdin());
        }
    });
    rx
}

pub fn get(rx: &Receiver<ControlKeys>, old: ControlKeys) -> ControlKeys {
    match rx.try_recv() {
        Ok(key) => key,
        Err(_)  => old
    }
}

fn read_stdin() -> ControlKeys {
    let mut reader = stdin();
    let mut buf = &mut [0u8; 10];

    match reader.read(buf) {
        Err(why) => panic!(...),
        Ok(size) => {
            // read buf
            return res;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Threads or async/await and channels might be the right solution, perhaps most of the time. If just wanting to do O_NONBLOCK read()s without having to interface directly with libc, I found [nonblock](https://lib.rs/crates/nonblock) to be a useful and good enough crate.

Comment: How to asking the thread about received data while it's blocking waiting for potentionally more data?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer a thread might forward the data to the channel, which would have the non-blocking `try_recv` method

Answer (score 19):

Converting OP's comment into an answer:

You can spawn a thread and send data over a [channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/std_misc/channels.html). You can then poll that channel in the main thread using [try_recv](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_recv).

```
use std::io;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::Receiver;
use std::sync::mpsc::TryRecvError;
use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    let stdin_channel = spawn_stdin_channel();
    loop {
        match stdin_channel.try_recv() {
            Ok(key) => println!("Received: {}", key),
            Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => println!("Channel empty"),
            Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => panic!("Channel disconnected"),
        }
        sleep(1000);
    }
}

fn spawn_stdin_channel() -> Receiver<String> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<String>();
    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        tx.send(buffer).unwrap();
    });
    rx
}

fn sleep(millis: u64) {
    let duration = time::Duration::from_millis(millis);
    thread::sleep(duration);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Multi-threading is Rust's forte.

Comment: How do I get rid of the spawned thread after timeout exceeded because it's stuck in a blocking read?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You can't. The possibility of this happening is the downside of this simple solution.

Comment: If the receiver were to be dropped, calling `send` will return `Result::Err`, which will cause a panic if `unwrap`ped and is one way to get rid of the spawned thread. You could also use `if let Err(_) = tx.send(buffer) {break;}` to gracefully exit the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could also potentially look at using [ncurses](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs) (also on [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/ncurses)) which would allow you read in raw mode. There are a few examples in the Github repository which show how to do this.

Comment: none of its examples is using non-blocking stdin read

Comment: The OP explicitly said they want to avoid a big dependency. I still believe there is value in an answer like this, but I downvoted because you add nothing to the OP. If you would show an example of how to do that this post would be worthy.

Comment: The ncurses library is also horribly unsafe, it should honestly be renamed ncurses-sys because that's what it actually is.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question and got an answer that worked for me [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-handle-stdin-hanging-when-there-is-no-input/93512/2?u=suchapalaver), which I will copy below for convenience. As was pointed out to me, "`tokio` already comes with `impl AsyncRead for Stdin`, so you should be able to do something like":

```rust
async fn read_from_stdin_timeout(timeout: Duration) -> io::Result<String> {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    tokio::time::timeout(timeout, tokio::io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buf)).await??;
    Ok(buf)
}
```

Comment: Quoting [`tokio`'s docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/fn.stdin.html), "This handle is best used for non-interactive uses, such as when a file is piped into the application. For technical reasons, `stdin` is implemented by using an ordinary blocking read on a separate thread, and it is impossible to cancel that read. This can make shutdown of the runtime hang until the user presses enter.".