# How can I stop reading from a tokio::io::lines stream?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to terminate reading from a `tokio::io::lines` stream. I merged it with a `oneshot` future and terminated it, but `tokio::run` was still working.

```rust
use futures::{sync::oneshot, *}; // 0.1.27
use std::{io::BufReader, time::Duration};
use tokio::prelude::*; // 0.1.21

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel::<()>();
    let lines = tokio::io::lines(BufReader::new(tokio::io::stdin()));
    let lines = lines.for_each(|item| {
        println!("> {:?}", item);
        Ok(())
    });

    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(5000));
        println!("system shutting down");
        let _ = tx.send(());
    });

    let lines = lines.select2(rx);

    tokio::run(lines.map(|_| ()).map_err(|_| ()));
}
```

How can I stop reading from this?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your strategy, but it will only work with futures that don't execute a blocking operation via Tokio's `blocking` (the traditional kind of blocking [should never be done inside a future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735952/why-does-futureselect-choose-the-future-with-a-longer-sleep-period-first)).

You can test this by replacing the `tokio::io::lines(..)` future with a simple interval future:

```rust
let lines = Interval::new(Instant::now(), Duration::from_secs(1));
```

---

The problem is that `tokio::io::Stdin` internally uses `tokio_threadpool::blocking` .

When you use [Tokio thread pool blocking](https://docs.rs/tokio-threadpool/0.1.14/tokio_threadpool/fn.blocking.html) (emphasis mine):

> NB: The entire task that called blocking is blocked whenever the
>   supplied closure blocks, even if you have used future combinators **such
>   as `select`** - the other futures in this task will not make progress
>   until the closure returns. If this is not desired, ensure that
>   `blocking runs in its` own task (e.g. using
>   `futures::sync::oneshot::spawn`).

Since this will block every other future in the combinator, your `Receiver` will not be able to get a signal from the `Sender`until the blocking ends.

Please see [How can I read non-blocking from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012995/how-can-i-read-non-blocking-from-stdin) or you can use [tokio-stdin-stdout](https://github.com/vi/tokio-stdin-stdout), which creates a channel to consume data from `stdin` thread. It also has a **line-by-line** example.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comment and correcting my sentences.

I tried to stop this non-blocking `Future` and succeeded.

```rust
let lines = Interval::new(Instant::now(), Duration::from_secs(1));
```

My understating is that it would work for this case to wrap the blocking `Future` with `tokio threadpool::blocking`.
I'll try it later.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually the idea is Inside a `Future` wrap the blocking behavior with  Tokio's  `Blocking` otherwise don't use it inside Future. Only thing to know that closure that you wrap with Tokio's  `Blocking `  is **permitted to block indefinitely**, in your case thats what `Stdin` does.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Now that I understand my way of thinking, I will study more.