# Handling piped data stdin with Rust

Tags: rust, stdin

I'm having trouble with stdin in Rust. I'm trying to process stdin comming from a pipe on a linux terminal, something like grep for example.

```sh
echo "lorem ipsum" | grep <text>
```

Im using this in rust:

```rust
fn load_stdin() -> Result<String> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let stdin = stdin();
    stdin.read_line(&mut buffer)?;
    return Ok(buffer);
}
```

But the problem is that if I don't bring in any piped data I get prompted to write, I would instead like to return Err.

So basically, if I do something like:

```sh
ls | cargo run
user@machine: ~ $
```

All is good. But if I do not pipe any stdin:

```sh
cargo run
```

The program halts and waits for user input.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012995/how-can-i-read-non-blocking-from-stdin. By default, you are doing a *blocking* read, in which case it is not an error to have no data; the read simply waits (potentially forever) until there *is* data. You need a *non-blocking* read, which will produce an error if it cannot read data *immediately*. I don't know Rust well enough yet to suggest how to do that.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks. I'm pretty new here when it comes to asking so do I mark the question as solved, remove it due to being a duplicate or?

Comment: Your question will just be marked as a duplicate - please do not remove it. In case someone searches for similar stuff, that someone will find your question and follow to the duplicate - so basically duplicate questions are "search links" that help to find the real issue. I think you might also mark it as a duplicate yourself.

Comment: The proposed solution seems wrong for the OP's problem. The OP doesn't need a non-blocking read to produce an error if data isn't available _immediately_ - after all, the command that is piped into the Rust code might not do so immediately either. What the OP needs is to detect whether the standard input is a TTY or a pipe, e.g. as provided by [this crate](https://crates.io/crates/atty).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`atty` crate](https://crates.io/crates/atty) to test whether your standard input is redirected:

```
use std::io;

use atty::Stream;

fn load_stdin() -> io::Result<String> {
    if atty::is(Stream::Stdin) {
        return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "stdin not redirected"));
    }
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer)?;
    return Ok(buffer);
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    println!("line: {}", load_stdin()?);
    Ok(())
}
```

This results in the desired behavior:

```
$ echo "lorem ipsum" | cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
line: lorem ipsum
$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
Error: Custom { kind: Other, error: "stdin not redirected" }
```