# Rust async (?) stdin read from pipe

Tags: asynchronous, rust, stdin

I would like to implement a `async` stdin function for otherwise sync cli application.

I would like to take output from program **A** ( as a side note, I do not know how much data or how long it will take for the program A to finish) - and pipe it into my program **B** which is supposed to wait for all of the data and then process it.

I saw this question: [How can I read non-blocking from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012995/how-can-i-read-non-blocking-from-stdin) which kinda works but also loops forever and never actually brakes.

That is why I wanted to use `async` and `await` ( for the stream to close ? ) even tho it might not be the best approach. I looked into `tokio::io::stdin()` but implementing an `async` function into otherwise `sync` code comes with its drawbacks.

What would be the best way of approaching this problem?

Comment: why async ? Just spawn two threads and be done with it