# Cancel synchronous stdin().read_line() from asynchronous environment

Tags: asynchronous, rust, stdin, rust-tokio

I have one asynchronous worker function that collects user input from `stdin` and sends it to other parts of the application. On shut down of the application, I would like to cancel my call to `std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_input)` and return from this function.

I can not get this behavior to work. One of my attempts looks like this:

```
    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        let maybe_input_handle = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| {
            let mut user_input = String::new();
            match std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_input) {
                Ok(_) => Ok(user_input),
                Err(e) => Err(e),
            }
        });
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        maybe_input_handle.abort();  // I would like the spawned task to be cancelled immediately
        let res = maybe_input_handle.await;
        println!("Result is: {:#?}", res);

        Ok(())
    }
```

When calling `.abort()` I would like the future of `maybe_input_handle` to resolve immediately, but instead on execution I have to press a button first, so that `read_line` can be resolved.
Is there a way to achieve my goal?
I considered to programmatically write to `stdin` in order to cancel the thread, but I could only find out how to write to the standard input of child processes.

Comment: how do you know your program should stop ?

Comment: Hi. Currently there are two exit conditions. One is via a user input (in this case of course I have no problem because the user "feeds" `read_line()`. The other option is via a network command. Currently, all my other worker tasks stop as I want them to stop (none are performing blocking I/O), I just do not know how to cancel this thread.

Comment: make a select and wait on both stdin and a async task that will tell you to stop, like a broadcast channel. That very similar to a answer I recently updated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458755/how-do-i-gracefully-shutdown-the-tokio-runtime-in-response-to-a-sigterm/53505771#53505771

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminating a function after 2 seconds of no stream items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75680180/terminating-a-function-after-2-seconds-of-no-stream-items)

Comment: Hi. @Stargateur's linked answer helped me to solve this issue. Thank you very much. drewtato thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @MYZ You can self-answer with the previous link and explain exactly what helped you. Helps those coming from Google.