# Interrupt and cancel io::stdin().read_line()

Tags: multithreading, rust, stdin

Is it possible to interrupt/cancel `io::stdin().read_line()` or interrupt stdin read before returning on a newline?

I have one thread polling for signals, which when received `SIGINT` should stop `io::stdin().read_line()`.

```rust
use std::io::Write;
use std::{io, thread};
use std::error::Error;
use std::sync::{Arc, atomic::AtomicUsize, atomic::Ordering};
use signal_hook::consts::signal;
use signal_hook::flag;

const SIGINT_U: usize = signal::SIGINT as usize;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let term = Arc::new(AtomicUsize::new(0));
    signal_hook::flag::register_usize(signal::SIGINT, Arc::clone(&term), SIGINT_U).unwrap();
    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        match term.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
            0 => {
                // do nothing
            }, 
            SIGINT_U => {
                // interrupt running read_line()
            }, 
            _ => unreachable!()
        }
    });

    loop {
        print!("> ");
        io::stdout().flush().unwrap();

        let mut line = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut line)
            .expect("Failed to read stdin");

        let command = line.trim_end().trim_start().to_lowercase();
        if command == "exit" {
            break;
        }

        println!("received: {}", line);
    }
}
```

The effect should be the same if we instead put `io::stdin().read_line()` into a separate thread and the `SIGINT` check inside the main loop.

The problem is, when `read_line()` is reached, stdin won't stop being read until a newline character is reached. This is the standard and expected behavior, but I'd hope I could somehow stop its execution. Albeit through stopping killing a thread running it, or somehow cancelling its return and stop without reading stdin.

I did try to put `read_line()` on a separate thread and detect when `SIGINT` was received. But it wouldn't matter, because the thread loop can't be stopped while `read_line()` executes, only before or after it.

I thought that maybe I could kill the thread running `read_line()`, but apparently it's not possible to kill threads.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve what you are asking for using the normal `std::io` library. Would you be open to switch to [async_std](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/)? Because with it, your problem would be trivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read non-blocking from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012995/how-can-i-read-non-blocking-from-stdin)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @drewtato, but I've already tested this exact solution before hand and even mentioned it on the question: _"The effect should be the same if we instead put io::stdin().read_line() into a separate thread"_

Comment: @Finomnis thanks! I'll try to look into async. I'm trying to do this on Windows, but I wanted a simple and as portable way as possible.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Even if you use tokio and their stdin handler, canceling the future will block the runtime, it's stated in the docs:

https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/struct.Stdin.html#

"For technical reasons, stdin is implemented by using an ordinary blocking read on a separate thread, and it is impossible to cancel that read. This can make shutdown of the runtime hang until the user presses enter.

For interactive uses, it is recommended to spawn a thread dedicated to user input and use blocking IO directly in that thread."

Comment: @alejandrodnm honestly, at the time I gave up on doing this myself so I just went and used the rustyline library, which can detect interrupt signals in the middle of user input. I don't know if it's overkill for your purposes, but in that case you might want to look into its code for how the library actually does this. Though I think rustyline does this in a platform-dependent way.

Comment: Hey @Willian . I decided that I'm ok with users having to do an extra Enter if they send a CTRL-c when if the tool is waiting for input. I'll take a look at rustyline though. Thanks