# Is there a way to listen to signals on Windows

Tags: windows, signals, rust

I'm writing a small shell for Windows in Rust, and want to kill the `Command` I spawned and prevent my shell from quitting.

Is there a way of capturing the Windows `SIGINT` equivalent in Rust?

Comment: The Windows console (conhost.exe) generates events in attached processes, such as `CTRL_C_EVENT`. Console processes can set handlers for these events. If the process is using Microsoft's C runtime, it installs a handler that calls its registered handler for the standard C `SIGINT` signal. If rust uses a CRT, it may provide a mechanism to ignore `SIGINT`, or at least some interface that lets you call C `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)` or Win32 `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, TRUE)`.

Comment: I know that I could use FFI, however I would _like_ (not need) a somewhat native way to do this.
(If someone tells me I need to use FFI, I will accept an Answer in that vein)

Comment: Yeah, I said 'SIGINT equivalent' for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a crate](https://crates.io/crates/chan-signal), `chan-signal`, that aims to help in handling this, by spawning a thread and having it wait for signals.

EDIT: It doesn't currently support windows.

There is [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1368) asking for this functionality to be integrated into the language's standard library, but it is very young.

It seems your option is to go with FFI.

Comment: If you do go the FFI way, please consider contributing to chan-signal, the author is [looking for support](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/chan_signal/#platform-support-no-windows-support) in that front.