# How to get tokio-io's async_read for a File handle

Tags: file, asynchronous, rust, streaming, rust-tokio

I want to stream lines out of a file handle and I do not know how to satisfy the trait bound that a `File` has `async_read`:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{ BufReader, BufRead };
use tokio_core::reactor::Handle;
use tokio_io::io::lines;
use tokio_io::AsyncRead;

struct DockerLog {
    path: String
}

impl DockerLog {
    pub fn new(path: String) -> DockerLog {
        DockerLog {
            path: path
        }
    }
    pub fn read_lines(&self, handle: &Handle) {
        let file : File = File::open(&self.path[..]).unwrap();
        let l = lines(BufReader::new(file));

    }
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::fs::File: tokio_io::AsyncRead` is not satisfied
  --> src/container/docker_logs.rs:20:17
   |
20 |         let l = lines(BufReader::new(file));
   |                 ^^^^^ the trait `tokio_io::AsyncRead` is not implemented for `std::fs::File`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `tokio_io::AsyncRead` for `std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>`
   = note: required by `tokio_io::io::lines`
```

Looking over the [`AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.1.2/tokio_io/trait.AsyncRead.html), it seems like a `File` doesn't mark that it has non-blocking reads. Do I need to downgrade the `File` to a `raw_fd` and then do something there?

Comment: Generally, filesystems *don't* have async IO (or not reliably). Which platform are you on that does?

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware of that. I'm just targeting Linux. What's the best way of streaming lines from many files? Sounds like I should spawn a thread per file (usually no more than 100 files).

Comment: Here's a (relatively) recent [article on the support for async file IO in Linux](https://lwn.net/Articles/671649/). The common solution is to have a threadpool and a queue. If you are using Tokio, something like [futures-cpupool](https://crates.io/crates/futures-cpupool) would be the first place I'd turn.

Comment: FYI `let file : File = File` is redundant — we don't need to write old-school Java here. `let file = File` is sufficient.

Comment: The new tokio release comes with a tokio_fs crate finally supporting async files, see https://tokio.rs/blog/2018-05-tokio-fs/

Comment: @Shepmaster But async IO can be emulated by adding a thread.